# SQL how to put values on one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, aggregate-functions

It is necessary that in the second column in a single line should be all related accounts.

This shows an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

```
SELECT [UserID],
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + UserID
FROM #RelatedIDs
WHERE (UserID = t.UserID)
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS RelIDs
FROM #RelatedIDs t
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Your subquery is just going repeat `UserId` a bunch of times.  You should ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONCAT()` instead of `+`:

```
SELECT [UserID],
       STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(', ', UserID)
              FROM #RelatedIDs ri
              WHERE ri.UserID = t.UserID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, '') AS RelIDs
FROM #RelatedIDs t
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Notice that I also changed the stuff arguments from `1, 1` to `1, 2`.  That is because you have a space after the comma.

Your correlation clause also suggests that the results will not be very interesting, when you get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, but you`re right, values are repeated in the second column, but I need unique onle. Can I do it?

Comment: @AnastasiiaVerbytska . . . Ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  Your question here has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You could `cast` the integer value to a varchar:

```
SELECT [UserID],
STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(UserID as VARCHAR(100))
FROM #RelatedIDs
WHERE (UserID = t.UserID)
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS RelIDs
FROM #RelatedIDs t
GROUP BY UserID
```

If you are running a recent version of SQL Server (2017 or higher), you can get the same result in a much less obsfucated manner with `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT t.UserID, STRING_AGG(r.UserID, ',') RelIDs
FROM #RelatedIDs t
INNER JOIN #RelatedIDs r on r.UserID = t.UserID
GROUP BY t.UserID
```

With the query put this way, it is plain to see that it makes little sense. The self-join operates on the same column as the one that defines the group, so this will just generate a list of identical `UserID`s in column `RelIDs` (one per occurence of the given `UserID` in the original query).